# How to Call event on Fragment Close/Deactivate/Dispose

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xamarin

I am Giving a Confirmation Dialog vie DialogFragment to User Which have one (Okay Button)
If User press Okay Button  i it Goes to The Second Activity and Perform Some Operation, but If user Click Outside the Fragment, the Fragment Hides and remain in the Same Activity Screen,
Is There Anyway to Call Event when the DialogFragment deactivates or hide.

i am using This Code to Show FragmentDialog Class

```
       private void user_Registered()
       {
           FragmentTransaction transaction = 
           FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
           UserRegistered obj = new UserRegistered();
           obj.Show(transaction,"sss");
       }
```

AND this is  FrameDialogCustomizedClassCode:

```
 public class UserRegistered : DialogFragment,IOnClickListener
{


    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.User_Registered, container,false);
        Button btnOK = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnOkay);
        btnOK.SetOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        if (v.Id== Resource.Id.btnOkay)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(MainActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

[image: DialogFragment]

For Example :
This Fragment has Ok Button which perform some Action, But this Fragment Auto Hides when the User Click Outside the Fragment, and the Codes which need to be executed remains.

> **What i Want:** 
>   i want to stop the DialogFragment from being Cancelled,
>   or i want to call event then the Dialog Fragment is Cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can `override` method `OnCreateDialog` of class `DialogFragment` and create a `AlertDialog` inside it.

If you want to make your own customized Dialog, you can just Inflate your layout into the AlertDialog. And call method `alert.SetView(yourview);`

For example, you can define a `DialogFragment` class as follows:

```
 public class DialogFragment2: DialogFragment
{
       Context context;  

    public DialogFragment2(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
         var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.user_registered, null, false);

        Button btnOK = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnOkay);
        btnOK.Click += BtnOK_Click;

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
            alert.SetTitle("Custom Dialog");
            alert.SetView(view);
            alert.SetCancelable(false);

            //alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) => {
            //    Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Go!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            //});
            //alert.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (senderAlert, args) => {
            //    Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Cancelled!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            //});

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.Create();
            alertDialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

           return alertDialog;
        }

    private void BtnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            var intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(MainActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
    }    
}
```

And use like this:

```
FragmentTransaction transcation = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
 DialogFragment2 alertdFragment = new DialogFragment2(this);
 // Show Alert DialogFragment
 alertdFragment.Show(transcation, "Alert Dialog Fragment");
```

The result is :

[image]

Comment: You are using the Built-in Alert Dialog  , while i am trying to make my own customized Dialog as Shown.   Like You are Using set (cancelable as False) is their Anything in DialogFragment?

Comment: This Worked for me, i have moved on but still Need Better Answer.

Comment: Could you post more details about your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` and in dialog builder `builder.setCancelable(false)`

You can use following code (but in Kotlin):

```
class UserRegisteredDialog : androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment() {

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        return activity?.let {
            val inflater = it.layoutInflater
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            builder.setCancelable(false)
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_dialog_layout, null))
            val dialog = builder.create()
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
            return dialog
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not using AlertDialog.Builder(), Can you see the my code Again please?